# Populating a @mentions array from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

So, I am using the mention.js library to add a @mentionUser functionality into my application. I am wondering what is the best way to replace the array with an array I build, fetching users from my database.

I have build the query to fetch the users, I'm just not sure how to use the resulting array in jQuery below.

PHP code (pseudocode mostly, will ofc use PDO)

```
$fetchUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE organisationId = '1'");
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetchUsers)) {
    $results[] = $row['name'];
}
```

Thanks alot!

```
<textarea id="full"></textarea>

<script>
    $("#full").mention({
    delimiter: '@',
    users: 
    [{
        username: "ashley"
    }, { 
        username: "roger"
    }, { 
        username: "frecklefart123"
    }]
});
</script>
```

Comment: And where is php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your PHP script return a JSON encoded array of user objects...

```
$fetchUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE organisationId = '1'");
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetchUsers)) {
    $results[] = array(
        'username' => $row['name']
    );
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

And then use jQuery's `$.getJSON`...

```
$.getJSON('/users.php', function(data) {
    $("#full").mention({
        delimiter: '@',
        users: data
    });
});
```

Simples :)

To answer your second question; use some regex (note my example is very basic)...

```
$string = '@matt @james @seb';

if (preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/i', $string, $matches)) {
    $mentions = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Oh god damn that is simple. Thanks Matt :D

Comment: Matt, could I bother you. What would be a nice way to generate a "notification" based on a mention. How could I capture each mention?

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Just to clarify, the first line ($string), should one pass all the usernames into the string or was that just an example?

Comment: That was just an example; $string should be the contents of your input field that you have Mention.js attached to.